# mail marketing email shows error in opencart?

Tags: php, email, opencart, opencart2.x

I am trying to send marketing email from my opencart website, but i am not able to do so, whenever i try to send nothing happens when i checked the console it shows

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).code is not a function

send    @   index.php?route=marketing/contact&token=wEqTvvsz0jV5OjK6swHumYMe8I6f7XbN:638
onclick @   index.php?route=marketing/contact&token=wEqTvvsz0jV5OjK6swHumYMe8I6f7XbN:269
```

[image]

above is the image when i comment .code() part the emails are going but the message shows [object object] in body.. however subject is perfect?

current file is in /admin/view/template/marketing/contact.tpl

any help..

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer i just comment out that line

```
//$('textarea[name=\'message\']').val($('#input-message').code());
```

now everything seems to work properly .. atleast for now ;)